# Password hashed twice on edit - CakePHP

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I have a user edit View. When people access this view it has the hashed password in the password block.

If you click save, it (obviously) hashes the password again, due to this being in my User model.

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if(!empty($this->data['User']['password'])) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

But I don't want to have it hashed twice (because it means the password has changed). I changed the edit view and added `array('value' => '','autocomplete'=>'off')` to the password field. Now when I save it, it saves a blank string in the database. I thought that it prevents it from doing that with the `if(!empty($this->data['User']['password']))` statement in the `beforeSave` function.

How would I prevent the password from being double hashed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is fairly simple. Simply change the if statement in beforeSave from:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if(!empty($this->data['User']['password'])) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

to:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if(!empty($this->data['User']['password'])) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    } else {
        unset($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Compare the hashes:**

You can compare the hash saved in the database against the text in the password field. If you haven't touch the password (changed the password field), the hashes should match. Let's say your saved hash is `xyz`, and the hash loaded in the password hash is still untouched, `xyz`; in this case you don't have to rehash anything, and the hashes should remain the same.

In the other case, let's say your saved hash is `xyz`, but you edited the password html field to be `abc`; in this case you will have to rehash the new password (`abc`) and then replace the old one you have in the database record.

**All of this can be translated in code as follows:**

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {

        if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['id'])) {
            $id = $this->data[$this->alias]['id'];
            $user = $this->findById($id);
        } else {
            $id = false;
        }

        if(!$id || $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] != $user['User']['password']) {
            $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

Regards,
M

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternate field name in your views (e.g. `$this->Form->password('pwd')`)

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['pwd'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['pwd']);
 }
    return true;
}
```

This prevents the password from being overwritten/blank. 
Credit, explanation and other best practices [at this link.](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually user edit pages are different from what you describe. If you store hashed passwords, the password is never returned in an edit view.

If a user wants to change his password a form contains usually 3 fields

- old password
- new password
- new password (to check if it equals the previous one)

What happens then is:

- Check if the two new passwords have equal values
- Hash old password
- Hash new password
- Check if old password hash equals the hash in the database... If so the old hash will be replaced by the new hash

In your example you cant differentiate between a hash and a regular password so your code will probably never work in its current state because a hash is also simply a String literal.

Comment: Here's the thing, this form is for our IT department to reset user passwords if a user asks for it. But IT can also change the name or surname or group of a user. So it's not definite that they will change the password. The password MIGHT be changed on user edit, or it may not. So what would I do when it's not changed? In my code I check if that field is empty, and if it is, I don't want to alter the database value. But it does. It removes the DB value and saves an empty string.

Comment: You probably need to check the sql statements then.

Comment: Wow, after reading how the data is sent to the database, it made sense on how to have it not save an empty field. Simply by stating `unset($this->data['User']['password']` if the password field is empty it removed that from the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if(AuthComponent::user('id') == null)
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
        return true;
}
```